# Sliced sudoku: rearrange the tiles and then solve it

Tags: sudoku, tiling

Rearrange the tiles without rotating nor flipping them to form a $9 \times 9$ sudoku. Then solve the sudoku according to the standard rules.

[image]

<sup>Credits: the sudoku is one of the twelve schemas freely downloadable from [websudoku.com](https://websudoku.com) for syndication. I made the tiling by myself.</sup>

EDIT: corrected picture

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I think the cell with the number 8 on the I-block should be moved one spot to the right?

Comment: @jafe yes sorry, I'll update the picture

Comment: @jafe - looking at the timestamps, you asked your question long before I completed mine, so you probably would have finished before me if you had received a quick answer. If you upload a completed version, I will withdraw mine.

Comment: @jafe - Please upload an answer, and I will withdraw mine. It is the fair thing to do.

Comment: @LannyStrack Actually I stopped when I spotted the discrepancy, so I have no solution to post :)

Comment: @jafe - OK, but if you had received a quick response to your question, you could have done it first. I will keep mine up for now, but if you decide to solve it and post an answer I will withdraw.

Comment: @LannyStrack Sorry about that, I updated the picture now. I can accept (at)jafe's answer if they post and if it is fine for you. How could you two possibly imagine that that particular square was the wrong one?

Comment: @melfnt - Yes, it is fine for me. Thanks. As for that square, the gap in the lower part of the dark blue piece is very conspicuous, and as I started to solve the puzzle, I immediately looked there to see which piece would fit. No piece could fit as-is without rotating or flipping, and piece "I" is the only one that came close to fitting. Piece "G' could also almost fit, but several changes were needed to make it fit, whereas only one small change was needed for piece "I" to fit there.

Comment: @LannyStrack I've accepted your answer since it has been a long time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution...................

> [image: img]